# How to animate part of a view transformation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I recently stumbled upon a problem where I have a view that can be rotated by the user. During the rotation it should, however, be 10% larger (scaled up).

I want that scaling to be animated but the rotation to be be visible immediately since I set it without animation in the gesture recognizer's callback.

**Question:** Is it possible to update an `CGAffineTransform`'s rotation without intercepting the scale being animated, or is there no way around creating a wrapping view that gets scaled instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

I think a wrapper view for scaling would be the least error prone way.

If you desperately want to avoid that, you could try to create the scaling animation manually with an NSTimer. Maybe if you query the current transform value first and then modify it instead of replacing it by an independently created one (for the rotation and the scale), it could work.

I think an implicit UIView animation calculates all subsequent values in the beginning, so that would mess up your rotation.

Another way to go would be to lock the rotation while the scaling occurs. The downside is, that scaling and rotation wouldn't be simultaneously. Anyway you could create an iVar or property let's say `rotationLocked` and do sth. like this:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.rotationLocked = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
            [self scaleView];
        }completion:^{ self.rotationLocked = NO; };
    }
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        if (!self.rotationLocked){
            // do the rotation
    }
    if (gr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // do something else
    }
```

Comment: Idea is good but I want the user to rotate the view **while** it is scaling up.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to just say it's not possible and propose that rotationLocked later in your answer? I just want to accepted answer to be very precise if you read the first few lines.

Comment: Did it work with an NSTimer then? Or what did you end up doing?